# $query $builder variables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello iam kinda new to laravel and iam trying to learn scopes but I can't find any information about $query and $builder variables inside function parameters. Can someone explain why you need to use these variables because then you call scope method you don't pass any parameters.

Comment: Could you give an example of the function you are looking at?

Comment: check:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries and https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

Comment: You don't directly call a scope method, you declare something like `scopeCustom($query)` but you call it as `->custom()` so Laravel takes care of calling your custom method with the correct parameters.

Comment: But what $query variable does? What is its purpose?

Comment: Did the below answer solve your problem or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

The `$query`/`$builder` variable allows you to add the constraints to your query in the same way you would using an `Eloquent` model or `DB`

```
$query->where('admin', true);
```

Scopes basically allow you to take multiple constraints (where clauses, joins, having etc.) and make it so you only have to chain on the one method instead of adding the same logic in multiple places.

---

**Example**

Say you have a products table and you want to check that the item is `active` and has `stock`. If you're not using scopes you would have something like:

```
Product::where('active', true)->where('quantity', '>=', 1)->get();
```

Whereas, you could make a scope called `available` in your model:

```
public function scopeAvailable($query) 
{
    $query->where('active', true)->where('quantity', '>=', 1);
}
```

Then you could simply do:

```
Product::available()->get();
```

---

**Scopes can also take parameters**

Say we have an offers table where there is an `available_from` and `available_to` date and you want to get all the rows that were available for a certain date:

```
Offer::where('available_from', '<=', $date)
    ->where('available_to', '>=', $date)
    ->get();
```

or we can make an `availableOn` scope

```
public function scopeAvailableOn($query) 
{
    $query->where('available_from', '<=', $date)->where('available_to', '>=', $date);
}
```

Which would allow you to do:

```
Offer::availableOn($date)->get();
```